# $f_n \rightarrow 0$ but not the graphs.

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $H$ be the prehilbert space of functions $f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ which are continuous and square-integrable endowed with the $L^2$ real scalar product.

Let $(f_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ be a sequence in $H$ given by
$$
f_n(x) := \sqrt{n} e^{-nx^2}
$$
Then
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty} \|f_n(x) - 0\|_{L^2} = 0.
$$
So $(f_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ converges strongly to the function $f(x)=0$ (which is an element of $H$).

Nevertheless, the graphs of the $f_n$ don't seem to tend to the null function but rather to something that *looks like* a $\delta$-Dirac distribution (which is not an element of $H$).

Where's the problem ?

**Solved :** $\|f_n(x) - 0\|_{L^2} = \|f_n(x)\|_{L^2} = (n\pi/2)^{1/4}$ which doesn't tend to zero.

**End remark :** As proposed in the comments, I should have asked the question with
$$
f_n(x) := n^{1/4} e^{-n^2x^2}
$$
If my calculations are right, $\|f_n\|_{L^2} = \left(\frac{\pi}{2n}\right)^{1/4}$ so now I have $\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\|f_n\|_{L^2}=0$. Now, $\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\|f_n\|_{L_2}=0$ impliques $\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}f_n$ is null almost everywhere and not that it converges to $0 \in H$ (and in particular it doesn't imply that it converges in $H$).

Comment: We don't have $\lVert f_n\rVert_{L^2} \to 0$. In fact, the norms are proportional to $n^{1/4}$.

Comment: Thanks. I went too fast on that point. That answers my question.

Comment: Instead study $f_n(x) := n^{1/4} e^{-n^2x^2}$.

Comment: Yes I'm looking at it.